# Is it a best practice to only supply props shallowly in React components?

Tags: reactjs

I've noticed that React only freezes the props shallowly, and that React.cloneElement only merges in props shallowly. So should we only be passing in props shallowly when we can?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I mean is it a best practice to not pass in objects in to props? Such as the props should be `foo={true} bar={true}` not `baz= {{foo: true, bar: true}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely pass objects in props, I don't think it is a bad practice at all, although it's a good idea to define `PropTypes` on your component so that its users know what to pass in.

I'd also suggest looking into [making your model immutable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html). Immutable objects are always 'frozen', plus they have other benefits, like allowing you to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in a very efficient way, do deep comparison / deep cloning trivially etc. This kind of thing plays really well with react.

Answer (score 1):

I would say try to make them shallow when possible, but it really isn't feasible to always do that because you'd have to assume your data is super flat. On top that, react allows for you to pass objects with shape, so I imagine its ok to pass and object in.

For example, look at the Animal object below.

```
{
   name: 'Cow',
   sound: 'Moo',
   size: {
     height: 50,
     width: 200
   },
   origin : {
     location: { 
        lat: 42.42,
        lng: 83.02
     },
     name: 'Cow Land'
   }
}
```

You may decide to build out an animal card that takes in an object. It may have a specific shape that has most of these props.

Within the card, you may want to use most of the properties. However, location is a nested object and may also be described with maybe a location component you have.

At some point, your data is going to have to come in from somewhere. If this animal object is part of a larger one, then passing in single props by dotting into the nested paths would be too burdensome and bloat one component too much.

I would suggest being clear about what your objects look like when they go down the component chain. Components are supposed to be composable so I would also imagine just breaking things down as much as possible. A component may be made of smaller components which handle the nested structure of data. From there, keeping to unidirectional data flow will help make it so your data is immutable.

Ultimately, use your discretion on deciding when you should be passing in primitive values verses maybe an object with shape.

The react examples show a bit of both.

```
var ProductRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
            this.props.product.name :
            <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
                {this.props.product.name}
            </span>;
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

In this example, they are dotting on the product which is on the props. So this component is taking in a product object with an assumption of what is on it.

Good luck!