# What is the correct way to pass props to component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to know which is a better method or the "correct way" to pass props to a component, in object or plain props:

plain props:

```
{ this.props.data && this.props.data.map((item) => {
  return(
    <MyComponent title={ item.title } thumbnail={ item.thumbnail } />
  )
});
}
```

or object:

```
{ this.props.data && this.props.data.map((item) => {
  return(
    <MyComponent singleItem = { item } />
  )
});
}
```

Which I should use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a best practice to only supply props shallowly in React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215234/is-it-a-best-practice-to-only-supply-props-shallowly-in-react-components)

Comment: I think this is more concise question, but if community thinks this are duplicate,I will delete this question,thanks for your suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either should work. However, if you plan on using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to minimize re-rendering and either of `title` or `thumbnail` are JS primitives then you should pass them separately to take advantage of shallow equality.

If you want to pass them the `props` separately but still want to not have to write the props separately, you can use the spread notation:

```js
<MyComponent {...item} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with should ComponentDidMount cycle and spread anotation (before doesn't works, idk why,maybe react version.) but now works perfect. This will be correct answer.Thanks for your time.